# The linker cannot find assembly function connected with C++ program

Tags: c++, assembly, linker, clion, gnu-assembler

I wrote assembly function and main in C in VS Code and compiled it a standard command

> gcc charFull64.s file.c -gstabs -no-pie -o ex

The program was linked and worked. Then I tried to add them to the project in **CLion**. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same problem that the linker cannot find my assembly function. I tried to add some flags in the CMake and find an answer on the internet, but I can't.

Probably a significant part of the function program (*charFull64.s*):

```
    [...]
    .text

    .global fullChar
    .type fullChar , @function

    #int fullChar (unsigned char*);
    fullChar:
      push %rbp              
      movq %rsp, %rbp
      pushq %rbx
      pushq %r12
      pushq %r13
      movq %rdi, number  # unsigned char* to number
    [...]
```

And my main in *file.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int fullChar (unsigned char*);
int main(){

    unsigned char a[] = "514";

    int size = fullChar(a);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Clion** still throws this:

```
CMakeFiles/program.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/stanley/CLionProjects/Factorization/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `fullChar(unsigned char*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/program.dir/build.make:90: recipe for target 'program' failed
```

I don't know how to solve it anymore.

Comment: The error message refers to `main.cpp.o` but your question says `file.c`. Decide which one. If it is indeed a C++ file and you use C++ compiler you should use `extern "C"` to indicate C name mangling. You might also need to name your function `_fullChar` with a leading underscore.

Comment: Try `extern "C" int fullChar (unsigned char*);`.

Comment: `-gstabs` is unlikely to be what you want, unless you're using a debugger that only understands the very old STABS debug format, not DWARF.

Comment: `extern "C"` works :) Thanks